# Create multiple GCP storage buckets using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

I have used terraform scripts to create resources in GCP. The scripts are working fine. But my question is - how do I create multiple storage buckets using a single script.
I have two files for creating the storage bucket-
main.tf which has the [terraform code](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket) to create the buckets .
variables.tf which has the actual variables like storage bucket name, project_id, etc, which looks like this:

```
variable "storage_class" { default = "STANDARD" }
variable "name" { default = "internal-demo-bucket-1"}
variable "location" { default = "asia-southeast1" }
```

How can I provide more than one bucket name in the variable name? I tried to provide multiple names in an array but the build failed.

Comment: If your question is about creating multiple resources (buckets) show the HCL that you used and the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know all your requirements, however suppose you need to create a few buckets with different names, while all other bucket characteristics are constant for every bucket in the set under discussion.

I would create a variable, i.e. `bucket_name_set` in a `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "bucket_name_set" {
  description = "A set of GCS bucket names..."
  type        = list(string)
}
```

Then, in the `terraform.tfvars` file, I would provide unique names for the buckets:

```
bucket_name_set = [
  "some-bucket-name-001",
  "some-bucket-name-002",
  "some-bucket-name-003",
]
```

Now, for example, in the `main.tf` file I can describe the resources:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "my_bucket_set" {
  project       = "some project id should be here"

  for_each      = toset(var.bucket_name_set)
  name          = each.value     # note: each.key and each.value are the same for a set

  location      = "some region should be here"
  storage_class = "STANDARD"
  force_destroy = true

  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}
```

Terraform description is here: [The for_each Meta-Argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html)

Terraform description for the GCS bucket is here: [google_storage_bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket)

Terraform description for input variables is here: [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html)

Comment: Thanks @al-dann. This is exactly what I was looking for. My requirement is pretty simple - just creation of multiple buckets. I have two folders- main and modules. Inside my main folder, I have the main.tf file, which calls the modules folder. Inside the modules folder, I have the main.tf and variables.tf. In this folder, I added the terraform.tfvars as you suggested. I am getting an error like "The argument "bucket_name_set" is required, but no definition was found." Trying to troubleshoot this, as I have already defined this arg in variables.tf

Comment: From the best of my understanding - "bucket_name_set" - is to be defined in some variables file. In my example above - in the "variabels.tf" file. You may need that in your "main" folder (as well as "tfvars" file), under assumption that your "modules" have no relevance to a list of buckets - I guess it does not really matter for the "modules" - how many buckets you are to create.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by providing the values in the variables.tf file itself. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using terraform provided modules ? It becomes very easy if you use gcs module for bucket creation. It has an option to specify how many buckets you need to create and even the subfolders. I am including the module below for your reference

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/cloud-storage/google/latest